# Parsing .java file to extract all features

Tags: java, class, static-analysis

I need to parse .java file to do static analyze and extract information from the file like:

1. variables
2. methods
3. annotations
4. inner classes
5. ...

I need to parse It at runtime something like this:

```
JavaClass c = parse("file.java");
c.getMethods();
```

I am not sure if there is any tool already exists, and if not can you please provide with some advice how to build it.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to use a good parser for that.

[ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) is a parser generator that comes with a huge library of ready to use grammars, one of which is [Java](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java). With that one it is easy to transform a java source file into an abstract syntax tree. On that tree do whatever analysis or transformation you need.

Comment: [*JavaParser*](https://javaparser.org/) is another such tool.

Comment: JavaCC is another.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [the JavaDoc API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html). It provides everything you need, and you do not even need to write a parser of your own.

Ok, in the beginning it is far from being intuitive, but the good thing is, it works along the same line as an AnnotationProcessor, so you learn two things in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Is your task an academic one? If not then I would consider supporting/joining an existing static analysis tool project like [spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/), [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/), ...

And does it really need to be `.java` files or can it also be `.class` files? Most available static analysis tools for java work on bytecode. So why reinvent the wheel?
[Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) for instance is using [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) and [ASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM).